# reference a table that was created via pandoc format

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

So I figured out how to put a caption and number on a table in an RMarkDown file:

```
kable(head(iris),format='pandoc',caption='hello')
```

Now when I render that in latex I get the output I want, but is there anyway way to throw a \label it so that I can do an inline reference to it using \ref{table} or maybe some kind of markup to do it?